# Closed form for ${\large\int}_0^\infty\frac{\arctan(x)\,\operatorname{arccot}(x+1)}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, trigonometry

I'm looking for a closed form for this integral:
$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan(x)\,\operatorname{arccot}(x+1)}{x}dx.$$
*Mathematica* and *Maple* could not evaluate it symbolically. Numerically,
$$I\approx1.3513049368715095284050230093075694014884142059538...$$
*WolframAlpha* and *ISC+* could not find a plausible closed form for this number. Still, I hope that it exists, because the integral looks nice.

Comment: @OlivierOloa c'est pour toi ça :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The integrand has a [closed-form antiderivative](http://gist.githubusercontent.com/VladimirReshetnikov/07666e0f48555ef817fb/raw/873ccea32397cf32019bbd762013adfaee0a3dd8/Antiderivative.nb) in terms of elementary functions and polylogarithms. It can be found using *Mathematica* after expressing inverse trig functions through logarithms of complex arguments, and can be manually checked for correctness using differentiation. After subtracting its limits at $\infty$ and $0$ and simplification, we can get this result:
$$\begin{align}I&=\frac1{32}\Big[\!\operatorname{Li}_2\!\left(\tfrac15\right)\cdot\ln2+\operatorname{Li}_3\!\left(\tfrac15\right)+
\operatorname{Li}_3\!\left(\tfrac45\right)\!\Big]+\frac{\pi}{16}\,\left(3\operatorname{Ti}_2(2)-4\,G\right)\\&+\frac{\ln5}{192}\,\left(9\ln2\cdot\ln5-12\ln^22-2\ln^25\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{192}\,\left(\ln5-7\ln2\right)+\frac{17}{16}\zeta(3),\end{align}$$
where $\operatorname{Ti}_2(x)$ is the [inverse tangent integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html), $G=\operatorname{Ti}_2(1)$ is the [Catalan constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html).

Comment: I used the same approach in Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks. I learnt something new  ( "$\ldots$expressing inverse trig functions$\ldots$" ).

Answer (score 2):

Using Mathematica I have arrived at the result

$$I=\frac{1}{4} (-\text{Li}_3(-1-i)-\text{Li}_3(-1+i)+\text{Li}_3(1-i)+\text{Li}_3(1+i))+\frac{1}{4}
   \left(-\text{Li}_3\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)-\text{Li}_3\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)+\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)+\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i
   }{2}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) \log \left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) \log
   \left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) \log \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) \log
   \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)\right)$$

Which matches your numerical estimates.

$$I\approx1.3513049368715095284050230093075694014884142059538$$

I am unable to simplify it past the polylogs. Running full simplify we can get to

$$\frac{1}{384} \left(48 \pi  C+3 \left(-64 \text{Li}_3\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)-64 \text{Li}_3\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)+32 (\text{Li}_3(1-i)+\text{Li}_3(1+i))+35 \zeta
   (3)\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) (-48 \log (2)-72 i \pi )+24 \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) (-\log (4)+3 i \pi )-4 \log ^3(2)+7 \pi ^2 \log
   (2)\right)$$
Where $C$ is Catalan's constant.

I think this is about as closed form as it is going to get.

Comment: These polylogarithms of complex arguments are very much simplifiable. Unfortunately, _Mathematica_ cannot do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In here we will find the anti-derivative of the integrand. It appears that the result can be expressed in terms of elementary functions and the poly-logarithm of order two. In order to arrive at the result the only thing we need to do is to use integration by parts and the definition of the poly-logarithm. We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int \arctan(x) \mbox{arccot}(x+1) \frac{1}{x} dx \\
&&=
\arctan(x) \mbox{arccot}(x+1) \log(x) - \int \left( \frac{\mbox{arccot}(1+x)}{1+x^2} - \frac{\arctan(x)}{1+(1+x)^2}\right) \log(x) dx  \\
&&= 
\arctan(x) \mbox{arccot}(x+1) \log(x) -{\mathcal I}_1(x) \mbox{arccot}(x+1) + {\mathcal I}_2(x) \arctan(x) + \\
&& \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad   -\int {\mathcal I}_1(x) \frac{1}{1+(1+x)^2} dx - \int {\mathcal I}_2(x) \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx 
\end{eqnarray} 
where 
\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathcal I}_1(x) &:=& \int \log(x) \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx = \frac{\pi}{4} \log(1+x^2) - \frac{1}{2 \imath} \left( Li_2(1+\imath x)-Li_2(1-\imath x)\right)\\
{\mathcal I}_2(x) &:=& \int \log(x) \frac{1}{1+(x+1)^2} dx=\arctan(\frac{x}{x+2})\log(x) + \frac{1}{2 \imath} \left(Li_2(-\frac{1+\imath}{2} x) - Li_2(-\frac{1-\imath}{2} x) \right)
\end{eqnarray}
The equations above have been derived by expressing the inverse polynomials into simple fractions and then relating the result to the definition of the poly-logarithmic function $Li_2(x) := -\int\log(1-x)/x dx$.

There was a mistake in the old version of my answer.More complicated integrals appeared. I will finished this post later and salvage this approach.